# SuiteScript 2.0 manually add items to communications tab

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to add email line items manually to the communications tab of a transaction but I can't seem to find any documentation on this. I would be very grateful for any guidance on this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `messages` sublist is not editable or dynamic, so you do not add items to it directly. Instead you add to it by sending an email via the `N/email.send()` API and providing the relevant transaction as a Related Record in the options.

Looks something like:

```js
email.send({
    author: "123",
    recipients: ["test@test.com", "another-test@test.com"],
    subject: "This is an email",
    body: "Probably the best email ever",
    relatedRecords: {
        transactionId: recordId // <-- relevant transaction ID here
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks that is awesome. I appreciate it. One last question if I may, how do I add a communications record to a customer if I send an email that is not connected to a transaction?

Comment: If the Customer is the recipient, the email will automatically show up in their Communications list; `relatedRecords` has other properties as well to link to other records types. Just check out the API in Help and you can see them all.

Comment: thanks once again, for example, I sent statements to a customer but it doesn't have specific transaction, so not having that and just sending the reference to the email does not show up in communications, thanks for all your help.